# How to store user input into a dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I need to create a function which accepts a name and age from user and store those values in a dictionary

I am not sure how to put the entries in a dictionary

```
prompt = "\nWelcome, please enter a name and age"
prompt += "\nEnter 'done' when finished. "
message = ""
while message != 'done':
    
input_name = input("\n name?") 
input_age = input("\n age?")
```

Comment: what have you tried? have you googled "how to get user input" and "how to assign to dictionary" - the two steps your function need to do?

Comment: Please give an example of the expected dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a function

```
dictionary = {}

name = input("name: ")
dictionary[name] = input("age: ")
```